# How to solve the following system of equations involving inverse sine?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$$10x=\sin^{-1}(38y)-\sin^{-1}(52y)$$

$$40x=\sin^{-1}(-53y)-\sin^{-1}(52y)$$

Multiplying across the first equation by $4$ and subtracting the equations gives:

$$4\sin^{-1}(38y)-3\sin^{-1}(52y)-\sin^{-1}(-53y)=0$$

I found a formula for adding inverse sine functions but only if the coefficients were similar.

How would I solve for $y$ in this expression ?